# Python code not executing in order? MySQLdb UPDATE commits in unexpected order

Tags: python, python-2.7, threadpool, mysql-python

I've got a Python 2.7 script I'm working on that retrieves rows from a MySQL table, loops through the data to process it, then is supposed to do the following things in this order:

1. UPDATE the table rows we just got previously to set a locked value
   in each row to TRUE
2. *After* the UPDATE query executes and commits via MySQLdb, a ThreadPool of processes should run on the data from the original loop.

What's actually happening is that the UPDATE query seems to be committing somehow after the ThreadPool is done. I tried refactoring it into a try/finally statement to make sure, but now it either still does it afterwards, or just doesn't commit the UPDATE and runs the ThreadPool anyways.

It's a head scratcher, to be sure. I assume I'm just doing something really wrong and obvious but not catching it after looking at this for so long. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Here's the gist:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, IMapIterator

import MySQLdb as mdb
import os, sys, time
import re

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.bucket import Bucket


...

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db')


with con: 

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT preview_queue.filename, preview_queue.product_id, preview_queue.track, products.name, preview_queue.id FROM preview_queue join `catalog_module-products` AS products on products.id = preview_queue.product_id where locked != 1")

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    mp3s_to_download = []
    lock_ids = []
    last_directory = ""

    if len(rows) > 0:
        for row in rows:
            base_dir = str(get_base_dir(row[1], row[3]))
            mp3s_to_download.append([base_dir, str(row[0])])

            if last_directory != "preview_temp/"+base_dir:
                if not os.path.exists("preview_temp/"+base_dir):
                    try:
                        os.makedirs("preview_temp/"+base_dir)

                    except OSError, e:
                        pass

            last_directory = "preview_temp/"+base_dir   
            lock_ids.append(str(row[4]))

        if len(lock_ids) > 0:
            action_ids = ','.join(lock_ids)

            try:
                cur.execute("UPDATE preview_queue SET locked = 1 WHERE id IN ({})".format(action_ids))
                con.commit()
            finally:
                pool = ThreadPool(processes=20)
                pool.map(download_file, mp3s_to_download)


                cur.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `finally` clause is guaranteed to execute, even if the `try` clause raises an exception. What is probably happening here is that an exception is being raised, preventing the update from being committed, but the threads are triggered anyway.

This doesn't really seen to be an appropriate use of try/finally. Rather, use a normal try/except to catch and log any exceptions, and then perhaps use an `else` clause to start the threads only if no exception was raised.

Comment: That's exactly it, just needed to use else instead of finally. I figured it would likely execute the finally: in order regardless of an exception, but else: seems to do it far more reliably. Thanks for the help!